# Question Mark button is too small, how do i make it pushable?

Tags: swiftui

I am building an app that has a helper modal, so a ? inside a circle is shown.

However the button appears to be too small to push, if I add a " ? " it seems to work but the button is offset.

Is there a way to make the hit box bigger?

```
HStack {
                        Text("Enter device ID. ").font(.custom("regular", size: 14)).foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)))
                            .padding(.bottom, 8)
                            
                        Button(action: {
                            self.isShowingModal = true;
                        }){
                            Text("?")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .font(.custom("regular", size: 14))
                                .background(Circle().stroke(Color.blue).frame(width: 17, height: 17))
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 8)
                        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingModal){
                            HelperModal()
                        }
                         
                    }
```

Comment: Is that family name on your font correct? If your family name isn't correct then the resizing won't work either.

Comment: Why not `Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")`?

Comment: Did you try to set frame `Text("?").frame(width: 30, height: 30)`?

Comment: Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle") fixed it... sorry thats a dumb mistake on my part. thank you @Asperi

Answer (score 0):

If you need to expand the tap area of a `Text`, you can apply `.frame` modifier along with `.contentShape`.

```
Text("Example text")
  .frame(width: frameWidth, height: frameHeight)
  .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Choose a shape you'd like to use
```